# How draw line at widget treeview

Tags: java, android

please help me. I try to create the line on listview how do that? 
may be need to use another piece of hardware and I do not know....
how to draw a line from the parent to the children?
need to use canvas or doing through picture?
**like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library:

[AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView)